# Assign a tag to an object in a unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a subway simulator, I want the `StationBox` to always have the `Created` tag after pressing a button, but it goes back to the previous value when the game is restarted, how can I solve this?

Update: I will have more than 1 station, I would like to make a universal script for all

```
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

public class AddStation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField Input;
    public Text StationName;
    public GameObject Button;
    public GameObject CreateStation;
    public GameObject StationBox;

    public void OnMouseDown(){
        if (Input.text != ""){
            CreateStation.SetActive(false);
            StationName.text = Input.text.ToString();
            StationBox.tag = "Created";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 questions...are you sure that section of code is being called?  (does `StationName.text` change).  Do you have a GameObject assigned to StationBox in the inspector?

Comment: @jiveturkey Yes, the text changes its value and the tag changes to "Created" when I click on the button

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to find a way to save game data so as not to lose it when you restart the game.
To do this the most practical solution is PlayerPrefs.
You can find a lot of documentation online because it's a simple concept.
However for your problem you can do this:

```
public void OnMouseDown(){
        if (Input.text != ""){
            CreateStation.SetActive(false);
            StationName.text = Input.text.ToString();
            StationBox.tag = "Created”;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(“Created”, 1);
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
       if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey(“Created”))
         if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt(“Created”) == 1)
             StationBox.tag = "Created”;
    }
```

Comment: This is a good solution but I will have more than 1 station, I would like to make a universal script for all, when placing this script on all stations, they will be created and edited all together

Comment: The original question did not specifically talk about this issue, so I recommend you create a new question and I will answer you there, so as not to get confused for future users. Also, if you have voted my answer positively thank you very much, but remember that it is not the correct way to accept a question. On your question page you should have a button to accept the answer.

Comment: Can you change your answer? I will add this condition to the question description

Comment: A new answer would be better so that future users can see this discussion with the solution, and the other question with another solution. The site guidelines say so.

Comment: I created a new question